# Why won't border-radius round off the actual border-style?

Tags: html, css

This was tested in Chrome, FF, and IE 10 and they all behave the same way, so I don't think it is some bug, but rather something I am doing wrong/not aware of.

Here's what I see:

[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
table#calendarTable
{
    border: 2px inset #888;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #61915f;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -ms-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    behavior: url(/Resources/PIE.htc);
}
```

And the parent div's CSS:

```
div.calendarWrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 215px;
}
```

As reading the CSS reveals, the actual calendar is a `<table>` element and it is that element that has the border-style, not the parent.

Note that I am using PIE, but that hardly matters to this question since this behavior is coming from browsers fully compatible with CSS3.

My only guess is that this new CSS rule doesn't play well with tables?

**Irrelevant Note:**

Please ignore the dreadful calendar colors. They are random atm.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or equivalent reproducing the problem?

Comment: That might be difficult, but I will try :)

Comment: You need to add border radius to the tds as well

Comment: @voidking not hard at all.  Only need the important bits:  http://jsfiddle.net/pLgMr/

Comment: Okay, try this, althought the navigation buttons are broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/dMen8/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`border-collapse: separate` should fix this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLgMr/2/

You'll probably want `border-spacing: 0;` as well to avoid any extra spacing caused by not collapsing borders.

**Edit:** Your fiddle updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/dMen8/4/

Comment: Thank you, but I require the use of `border-collapse: collapse;` (or the equivalent thereof)

Comment: @voidking Why?  I see no borders on any of your cells.

Comment: Well, Sir, it seems I am confused by the difference between `border-collapse: collapse;` and `border-spacing: 0;`, however, I have applied your solution and it works marvelously (I would be able to very quickly tell if any of my widths were changed, and they are not). You are a gentleman and a scholar, and your answer does not require me to write additional script. Care to mention the difference between the two aforementioned CSS rules?

Comment: `border-collapse` actually combines neighboring borders, with some fairly complex rules.  `border-spacing: 0` just removes all space between borders.  Since your cells have no borders, the two are roughly the same.  If you had borders you would see a difference.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. May I ask how `border-collapse: separate` was able to fix this issue? Hopefully this is my last question :)

Comment: @voidking I'm not 100% sure of the exact reason but it had something to do with combining the square borders of the cells with the rounded borders of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add border radius to the table cells as well.

```
.myOneCell td {
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px; /* The version without prefix should always come last because it isthe approved version */ 
}
```

EDIT:

```
.numerousCellTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.numerousCellTable tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
}
.numerousCellTable tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 0;
}
.numerousCellTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0  0 0 25px;
}
```

Comment: This is rather broken, unless you want *every* cell to be rounded.

Comment: Hey, thank you for educating me as to where the non-prefix version should go. I had no idea. I'm +1-ing you just for that. What do you mean by approved version, though?

Comment: So I just need to target the corner tds? This will require some scripting as sometimes the calendar has 5 rows and sometimes 6.

Comment: @VoidKing: By "approved" version, he means that `border-radius` is the official, W3C-documented property, and should be the one that takes precedence over the others (which are just vendor extensions, hence the prefix).  Last declaration wins, so.

Comment: This code works fine for one cell table. Most tables have numerous table rows with numerous table cells. In that case you need to target the top-left corner of top-left cell, the top-right corner of top-right cell, the bottom-left corner of bottom-left cell and so and so on

Comment: @cHao sorry to be so inquisitive, but I love (and am always in dire need of) expanding my programming knowledge, so I must ask, if the prefix rules were skipped/not recognized would they overwrite the property? Sorry not sure how this is bad practice. Just Curious

Comment: @VoidKing: The rule the browser recognizes last, is the one it uses.  Most times it won't matter too much, cause they'll be the same.  But if they weren't, and the standard rule came first, then it would lose out to proprietary, vendor-specific rules.  That's kinda the opposite of what we want to happen.  So it's better if the standard rule goes last.

Comment: @cHao Okay, well, believe me, I'm sure you're right and I will be definitely be wanting to adhere to best practices, so I will be writing it this way from now on (and correcting any current instances of this), but I don't think I 100% understand, however if you tell me that "if all of the values (e.g. the `25px` values I was using [irl it's only `5px`, but anyway...]) were the same this doesn't really matter?" then I think I can infer what I need to know.

Comment: @VoidKing: If the standard rule has the same params and behavior as the prefixed one, then it's not that big a deal.  But it's still better if the official one takes precedence.